# Squid delay pools delay_parameters bandwidth

Tags: squid, bandwidth

I can not understand the documentation about delay_parameters params in squid.

```
delay_pools 1
delay_class 1 4 
delay_parameters 1 -1/-1 -1/-1 -1/-1 600/8000
```

What is the difference between the first and second bandwidth (600 / 8000)? Why and when should I set diffent values?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numerators and denominators in the squid pool config have different meaning:

- Numerator is the volume of the flow buffer (bucket) in bytes
- Denominator is the max allowed flow rate in bytes per second

Think about the pool as a tank with two pipes. One pipe fills the tank while other drains it. Throughput of drain pipe defined by denominator. Numerator is the volume of the tank. When tank is big enough the drain can be flawless while income can be chaotic - because of other users activity.

Bigger numerator makes downstream smoother but laggy. Smaller numerator makes traffic shaping more accurate but downstream becomes wiggly.

Years ago I've used values like 65536/16000 but now I'm sure delay pools are not an appropriate tool for shaping at all. You have to use some packet queuing tools like ALTQ or, in my case, that was the IPFW/DUMMYNET from the FreeBSD. When I've introduced  the packet queuing shaper all users have said "Wow!".

Comment: With squid delays seems that connection is jerkily... I tried some speed test and the chart is a saw. I'm using squid in ubuntu server platform, what do you suggest to use? My goal is to heavy slow down some domain (I dont' want to lock them, just to slow down).

Comment: Anyway delay pools intended to shape traffic TO the some specific user, not FROM the some specific site. I'm not familiar with ubuntu, my primary system is FreeBSD. Google says that traffic control in the Ubuntu is performed by `tc`.

Comment: Though tools like tc, and I think ALTQ are IP based, where squid delay_pools allow you to shape based on the dstdomain (aka domain name of the url requested). I find this particularly handy for limiting windows 10 update downloads from MS, to force clients to use their LAN based p2p sharing more.

Comment: @BeowulfNode42 The good strategy for shaper is to divide the whole uplink dinamically between the actually active users. We should divide the uplink  on the `dst` basis rather then `src`. IMHO sure.